# How to display contacts' pictures in a square instead of in a circle?

Tags: contacts

Starting with Android Lollipop, contacts' pictures in the Contacts are shown as circles and not squared. (Which IMHO makes no sense, breaks the UX and wastes screen estate, but it's not the point of the question so let's not spend time on it.)

There is clearly no way to change that in the system settings, but is there any 3rd-party contacts app that shows pictures as squared?

Answer (score 0):

> Which IMHO makes no sense, breaks the UX and wastes screen estate

You're the first I'm hearing that from, as in the circles wastes screen estate compared to the square ones.

Well, if you could get the apk for this contacts app on Techno C8, it might be able to give you something closer to your heart desire.

[image: border-radius contact images]

Comment: Do you have a link for this app on Google Play? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @dr01 Nope. Its an app that comes with the Techno C8